# Android VideoView Incorrect Colors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I am playing a video encoded with VP8 in a VideoView without a media controller. The video plays fine; however, the video is rendered as if the contrast has been adjusted. The background color of the video is supposed to be pure white but it looks slightly gray.

- I've tried a different encoding. The result is the same, ignoring artifacts.
- I've tried disabling or forcing hardware acceleration in the activity.
- I've tried creating the view with software rendering. The video doesn't play in this case.
- I've verified that in a desktop media player or embedded in a webpage through Chrome, Firefox, and Edge that the background color is rendered correctly.

How do I get the video to render correctly? Is this an issue with color profiles, and if so, how do I resolve that?

### View

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/main_room_video_frame"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

  <VideoView android:id="@+id/main_room_video"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="256dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

### Code

```
    _brandingImageViewLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.main_room_video_frame);
    _brandingImageView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.main_room_video);

    _brandingImageViewLayout.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.border);

    _brandingImageView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(
        string.Format("android.resource://{0}/{1}",
            PackageName, Resource.Raw.logo_256)));
```

### Border Resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#eeeeee" />
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

---

### Specifications

- KitKat 4.4.2
- LG 10SM3TB
- Xamarin.Android 7.0.2.37

Comment: What do you mean by "not matching"? Should video just cover the whole videoview?

Comment: I edited the question to be less ambiguous. The video has a pure white background and so does the view. Unfortunately the video is rendered with what feels like a contrast adjustment so the background color of the view does not match the video. It's jarring.

Comment: can you provide your "border" xml?

Comment: The background drawable doesn't appear to make a difference in how the video is rendered. I included it anyway.

Comment: Does this happen only on that device? I cannot see the problem on Huawei

Comment: The videoview doesn't have any background. Actually if I set background on videoview I cannot see the video. So the frame of the view has white background. I played with frame background color and border color but it doesn't seems to affect colors

Comment: If you want to change the VideoView background color you actually have to implement your own view using SurfaceView. I haven't tried that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130040/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-chris-hutchinson).